# Describe and apply Java code refactoring automatically for external dependencies

Tags: java, refactoring, automated-refactoring

Example: A library is renaming a method and deprecating the old one.

Is there a way to describe this refactoring, e.g. in XML and apply it to all dependent projects with a tool?

For clarification: When this refactoring is done, the library contains already the new code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at [Jackpot](https://bitbucket.org/jlahoda/jackpot30/wiki/Home).

Another tool of interest is google's [refaster](https://github.com/google/Refaster) could help. I have asked for its status here: https://github.com/google/error-prone/issues/384

Finally I am pretty sure [DMS refactoring](http://www.semdesigns.com/Products/DMS/Refactoring.html?Home=Main) supports such use case, even though I have never used it.